# Don't include apostrophe s in Spacy named entities

Tags: spacy

Is there a way to avoid an apostrophe s being included in a named entity, and keep it as a separate token?

For example, I would like to keep the "'s" separate after merging the ents in the following sentence

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

s = 'Donald Trump\'s role in the negotiations.'
doc = nlp(s)

for ent in doc.ents:
    ent.merge(tag=ent.root.tag_, lemma=ent.text, ent_type=ent.label_)

for t in doc:
    print(t)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In spaCy 3 you can create a [custom component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) to solve this problem. Note that entities (Spans) aren't mutable so you need to replace the entity with a new Span.

```py
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens.span import Span

@Language.component("no_possesive")
def no_possesive(doc):
    doc.ents = _no_possesive_generator(doc)
    return doc

def _no_possesive_generator(doc):
    """Yields non possessive versions of the given document's entities."""
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.text.endswith("'s") or ent.text.endswith("’s"):
            yield Span(doc, ent.start, ent.end-1, label=ent.label)
        else:
            yield ent

if __name__ == "__main__":

    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    nlp.add_pipe("no_possesive")

    assert nlp("Donald Trump's role in the negotiations.").ents[0].text == "Donald Trump"
```